# Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server operation issues

Tags: c#

I build a form application in Visual Studio 2019. When I insert data from a form into my database; when executing:

```
SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(str, sqlconnect);

int s = sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the following error:

> Syntax error near 'StudentID'.

[image: error image]

Comment: Your code in your screenshot mentions MySQL, but you're using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` which is intended for use with MS-SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Are you targeting MS SQL Server or MySQL Server (or MariaDB)? Or a different RDMBS like PostgreSQL, Access, etc.

Comment: I cant read the exception message unfortunately. and i cant translate it because its in image.

Comment: Can you please add the exception message in english as text on your question?

Comment: Let me translate the exception for you guys :) It means syntax error near 'StudentID'. If you wonder. @MichaelRandall  - however unfortunately we can't see the SQL :(

Comment: Can you update the question with the SQL?